# how I create a Java web application in visual studio code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there is any command to create a **Java Web Project** like the command Create Java Project , in Visual Studio Code.

I need to create a Java Web Application from scratch and I don't know the folder structure that Visual Studio Code uses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct template available in Visual Studio Code that does this. One option is to clone an existing GIT repo  with a skeleton that matches the stack you need. For example like they explain in [Java Web Apps with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-webapp).

Another option is you visit a generator like [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) or [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/generators/) and let them generate a project and folder structure for you which you in turn load in Visual Studio Code. Note that Visual Studio Code can load any folder structure and does not mandate a folder structure itself.

P.s. you might need to install a number of extensions in Visual Studio Code to work properly with Java based web projects. A quick scan reveals plenty of those in the marketplace.